# Application does not start, cache size

Tags: android, sqlite, caching

I am encountering an issue regarding my application. My application has local database. it is a courier delivery service application. I have noticed that when my application cache size reaches to 32MB or above. The application does not start.

After I clear cache and clear data from the settings. Application runs smooth.

Can anyone please tell me what I have to do in order to overcome it?

Comment: First of all you have to clear cache data means suppose if your application start at that time all the cache data automatically clear when user open your application and for that try to search on google "How to clear cache memory automatically in android programatically".

Comment: Alright, let me check.

Comment: And if you want to clear cache memory every 2 or 3 minute when user using your application for that use Handler.